# Django - How do I redirect ie6?

Tags: django, internet-explorer-6, django-views

I want to send a user to a page on my site that prompts him to upgrade to a more recent browser if they are using ie6 or lower.

How can this be achieved in Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [Middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/). Specifically, you want to sniff the browser agent in the [`process_request`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-request) of your middleware, and return a `HttpResponseRedirect` if the browser agent indicates IE6.

There's a snippet that should get you started [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2001/). Do post a comment if you need help with it!